# Aggregate and create results list using EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm having a list of budget units each one containing the following properties:

```
DateTime Month,
int IdCurrency,
decimal Planned,
int sign, //denotes whether we have income (1) or cost (0)
etc...
```

Based on given year, I'd like to return a list of objects of the following structure:

```
public class BudgetBalances
{
    public DateTime Month { get; set; }
    public int IdCurrency { get; set; }
    public decimal Incomes { get; set; }
    public decimal Costs { get; set; }
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
}
```

The first part is easy - I'm getting all budget units for given day from the database, but now I do not know how to make an EF query to:

- Get all incomes (sign==1) in currencies within one month, sum them and store it Incomes property
- Get all costs (sign==0) and do the same as above
- Substract Cost from Income and store it under Balance property

As the result I will have

Jan2022, USD, 3000, 1000, 2000
Jan2022, EUR, 5000, 2000, 3000

etc..

I can always make three level foreach structure, but that is not an effective way to do so. Could you please give me hint how to do it proper way?

That is what I got so far:

```
public List<BudgetBalances>GetYearlyBudget(int IdOwner, int year)
        {

            var budgets = _context.Budgets
                .Where(_ => _.Month.Year == year && _.IdOwner == IdOwner);

            List<BudgetBalances> list = budgets.GroupBy(a => a.Month)
                .Select(ls => new BudgetBalances
                {
    Incomes = ls.Where(_ => _.IsIncome == 1).Sum(_ => _.Planned),
                Costs = ls.Where(_ => _.IsIncome == 0).Sum(_ => _.Planned) 

                }).ToList();
            return list;   
        }
```

And it calculates each month budget taking into account incomes and costs, but it does not take currencies into consideration. Also I do not know how should I obtain balance value.

```
Balance = Income - Costs
```

does not work

Comment: Can you post what do you have so far? You will need to group by on Month and then go from there. Also, what is the format of Month - Date and Time or just Date or some other format? Your expected result says USD for IdCurrency but in your class its defined as int.

Comment: I used string currency symbol only to bring more clarity. I will have something like this - 2022-01-01, 1, 3000, 2000, 1000l; 2022-01-01, 2, 5000, 2000, 3000; 2022-02-01, 1, 2000, 1000 ;

Comment: If you want it to consider currencies then you will need to add currency to group by like `.GroupBy(a => {a.Month, a.Currency})`  and for Balance you can have a getter in class as `Balance => this.Incomes - this.Costs`

Answer (score 0):

Reference [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/)

code sample

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    var result = context.BudgetBalances
                    .Where(b => b.IdCurrency == 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, finally I got what I wanted, here's my code:

```
public List<BudgetBalances>GetYearlyBudget(int IdOwner, int year)
    {
        var budgets = _context.Budgets
            .Where(_ => _.Month.Year == year && _.IdOwner == IdOwner);

        List<BudgetBalances> list = budgets.GroupBy(a => new { a.Month, a.IdCurrency})
            .Select(ls => new BudgetBalances
            {
                IdCurrency = ls.Key.IdCurrency,
                CurrencySymbol = _context.Currencies.Where(_=>_.IdCurrency==ls.Key.IdCurrency).FirstOrDefault().CurrencySymbol,
                Month = ls.Key.Month,
                Incomes = ls.Where(_ => _.IsIncome == 1).Sum(_ => _.Planned),
                Costs = ls.Where(_ => _.IsIncome == 0).Sum(_ => _.Planned),
            })
            .OrderBy(_=>_.Month)
            .ToList();

        foreach(BudgetBalances ls in list)
        {
            ls.Balance = ls.Incomes - ls.Costs;
            ls.month = ls.Month.ToString("MM/yyyy");
        }
        
        return list;
    }
```